# VBA: Or Operator not executing

Tags: vba

I am trying to use the OR operator in VBA, but I am getting an error when compiling. I have checked the syntax online, and I am sure I am using it correctly.

For example, if I do something like this:

```
 If CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "A1.2" Or "B1.1" Then
    Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
    End If
```

I get a Type Mismatch error. But, the following code executes:

```
If CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "A1.2" Then
        Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
        End If

If CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "B1.1" Then
        Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
        End If
```

Can some one please advise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I am sure I am using it correctly."* Nope. It's a boolean operator.

Comment: `CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "A1.2" Or CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "B1.1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write each criteria out longhand like,

```
If CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "A1.2" Or _
   CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)) = "B1.1" Then
    Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
End If
```

Alternately, stack the multiple OR criteria into an array and look for a match.

```
if not iserror(application.match(CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2)), array("A1.2", "B1.1"), 0)) then
    Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
End If
```

... or use a Select Case statement.

```
select case CStr(Worksheets("MINUTES").Cells(x, 2))
    case "A1.2", "B1.1"
        Worksheets("MINUTES").Rows(x).Hidden = True
    case else
        'do nothing
end select
```

The match-to-an-array works well with multiple OR conditions, the Select Case works well with multiple conditions and multiple outcomes.