# "or" statement not running inside an "if" statement

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I am kinda new to vba, so sometimes there is stuff that I cannot understand. Like why does this:

```
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
        For i = StartRow To LastRow
            If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "0" Or _
            Cells(i, iCol).Value <> vbNullString Then
                Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next i
```

does not work but if I separate both of the conditions it does work.

[VBA: Or Operator not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175147/vba-or-operator-not-executing)

[I use OR to form a multiple condition IF ELSE statement on VBA, it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803797/i-use-or-to-form-a-multiple-condition-if-else-statement-on-vba-its-not-working)

I have read this 2 previous stackoverflow posts and found a way to make it work:

```
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        Select Case Cells(i, iCol).Value
            Case vbNullString, "0"
                Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next i
```

but I still cannot figure out why the first one that I made was wrong.

Comment: You probably want to use an `AND` statement here. If `Cells(i, iCol).Value` is `0` then it necessarily is not `vbNullString` meaning at least one condition will always be true

Comment: but the thing is, I want to hide rows that people leave blank or fill with a zero. So, if I put an `AND`, doesn't it imply that the cell would have to simultaneously have a zero and be blank at the *same time*?

Comment: Even though I do not understand, the usage of `AND` makes the code run correctly.

Comment: Use and instead of or

Comment: The negation of (A or B) is (not A and not B).

Comment: Your doubts are related to the logic behind it, nor the code itself. I strongly suggest you understand the core behind this, this scenario can be seen under [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

Comment: ^^^^ and [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).